# How can I see MSIL code

Tags: c#, clr

I tried googling and searching StackOverFlow, but I'm not seeing an clear answer to this. How can I see the IL code that my C# gets compiled into? I want to compare two methods to see if they produce the same IL. I saw a really great video once of this guy looking at the IL code, but I forget what tools he used to look at it. I seem to remember the one had a tree-view where he could look around at the different objects in memory. I know he wasn't using Visual Studio.

Comment: [IL Disassembler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7dy01k1(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: The CLR (Common Language Runtime) is the runtime. What you're talking about is CIL (Common Intermediate Language), formerly known as MSIL.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [ILDASM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7dy01k1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (Intermediate language disassembler).

Other tools like [.NET Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/), <strike>[dotPeek](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/)</strike>, [JustDecompile](http://www.telerik.com/products/decompiler.aspx) or [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/) can also show the IL code, in addition to showing it in C#, Visual Basic .NET and/or other languages.

[LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) can also show the IL of your code snippets, but not the IL of arbitrary assemblies.

---

*EDIT: actually dotPeek only shows C# code, not IL*

Comment: ILDASM was the exact tool I saw in the video. Thank you!

Comment: There's an issue regarding IL support for DotPeek. If you'd like this feature, vote for it! https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DOTP-286